# Random scale and rotation for each particle on all axis separetly (Animation Nodes)

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

I'm looking for a way to randomize particles (objects) on all axis separetly, so I would get different shapes of them (not overall size). Just to give them a range for a random scale or rotation like 30% and they would get different shape each of them. I'm sure it's possible with Animation Nodes. Any hint about what kind of nodes I should use? Was experimenting with Vector Random but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You should make 3 random nodes, then combine them into one vector[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Vector Wiggle node which will generate a 3D Vector randomly based on the input seed. Click the "Add List" icon to generate a given list of random vectors.

Tweak the amplitude in order to constrain x,y, or z axis in a given range.

You can also animate it with the evolution input and the speed factor.

Animation nodes manual :

https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/vector/vector_wiggle.html